# Load more data when scroll bar rechead in last row in DevExpress GridControl using wpf?

Tags: devexpress, wpf-4.0, gridcontrol

Load more data when scroll bar reached in last row in `DevExpress` `GridControl` using wpf?
I have 100 rows in my `GridControl` in `DevExpress` but I want to Load 20 at the loading time and next 20 data will load when we scroll down in `GridControl`. Basically I want a event of `GridControl` when `GridControl` Scrollbar reached in last row, next 20 data will load, so is there solution please help me.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a behavior for this and attach it to TableView which is under GridControl. Also you can provide a command for behavior to execute when bottom is reached through attached property. Hope this helps.

```
public class IsScrolledToBottomBehavior : Behavior<TableView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new ScrollChangedEventHandler(OnScrollChanged));
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new ScrollChangedEventHandler(OnScrollChanged));
    }

    private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(((ScrollViewer)e.OriginalSource).VerticalOffset == ((ScrollViewer)e.OriginalSource).ScrollableHeight)
        {
            // do rows loading here
        }
    }
}
```